# Minecraft blocks disappearing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I mine a block in Minecraft the newest Version "vanilla Minecraft no mods just straight Minecraft" I was able to mine the block, but said block just vanished. It wasn't in my inventory or on the ground, it just went poof.
Can anyone tell me why or how I fix said problem?

Comment: Are you in survival mode or creative mode? Blocks mined in creative mode don't drop; this may be your problem. Michael's and TGPMinecraft's answers are also possible causes.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that you don't have the correct tool to mine the block but can still break it. For example, you can break stone found in the world however it will take a while to break it and you will receive nothing. I would suggest having a look at the following guide if this is the case: [Beginner's Guide](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Beginner%27s_guide).

If that is not the issue, it could be that your gamemode is set to 'Creative' in which case you will need to go about creating a new world or enabling cheats and changing your gamemode using the following command: `/gamemode survival`. You can enable cheats by going to the menu, selecting 'Open to LAN' and enabling the cheats option.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this problem. If you save and exit, then enter back in to it, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if '*dotiledrops*' is set to true. You can do this by using the command `/gamerule dotiledrops true`. Then try to mine something. This should work, but if it doesn’t, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I don’t know how to give text the highlight like that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bug I noticed in MC 1.14: if your inventory is full, sometimes you can no more add any collected item into it, but the block vanished.
Or, if you mine something without the right tool, it doesn’t drops any item. *Use a pickaxe, luke…*
and browse https://minecraft.wiki/w/Log#Chest_loot to validate the drop of any item when breaking with any tool.

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue when running the beta version of the game on a iPad mini. It was such a piece of trash and could hardly render about 50 blocks. When I was listening to music or multitasking on this ipad, whenever I mined a block, it broke but then if i put my crosshair on it there was still a outline. If I were you, I would check the minimum requirements for minecraft on ur device and if that doesn’t fix it, check that you are not in creative.

Comment: How in the world were you running Java Edition Beta on an iPad? That's a 10 years old piece of PC software.